# Displaying a UITabBar when pushing to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am working on a new project of mine and am looking for what the best solution to keep the `UITabBarController` displaying even when using a `segue` to push to a `UIViewController`.

Currently I have an `Initiation` of our `UITabBarController` on app launch, which contains `multiple` `viewcontroller` `relationships`.  Particularly the `initial view controller` option is a custom `UIViewController` which implements a  `UITableView`.  Once a `cell` is selected I call a `show(push) segue` to another `UIViewController`. This is where I lose my `TabBar` which is as expected.  Now I have tried different approaches such as setting the `hidden` value of our `tabbar` to `YES`, but does not seem to help.

---

`Code`

When Cell Selected:

```
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"tableCellOptions" sender: self];
```

When preparing for `segue`:

```
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tableCellOptions"]) {

        additionUITableView *move = (additionUITableView *) segue.destinationViewController;
        move.thisOption = [menuOptions objectAtIndex:cellPushed];
    }
```

What would your approach be to this and why?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Tab bar controller as the initial View Controller, the tab bar will show by default on each view controller.
If you are using storyboard or xib file, then select the tab bar item in view controller and check its properties, and make sure "hide tab bar on push" is unchecked.

Programmatically you can do this,

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerToPush animated:YES];
```

Place it in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: No this does not help any.  I am not programmatically pushing the views.  Plus `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` will not work.